# Get unix timestamp from mysql database with offset applied

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp, utc, convert-tz

I have the offset in seconds to UTC, all timestamps stored on the database are in UTC, how to apply the offset during selection queries,

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE unix_timestamp=unix_timestamp with offset applied");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (unix_timestamp) VALUES(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
```

I'd want to insert in UTC time to the database and retrieve in local time.

On PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$user_timezone_offset=-7200; // -2
```

Could I substract on select's runtime of mysql to the unix_timestamp field $user_timezone_offset and that would be it?

I am inserting in UTC which is what I need apparently, but for selection in user's local time I'd need to apply the offset to the timestamp stored in the database somehow.

Edit: I just came across this:

```
$user_timezone_offset="-2:00";

FROM_UNIXTIME(CONVERT_TZ(unix_timestamp,'+00:00','$user_timezone_offset'))
```

Would need to know how to apply it to a select query making the selection of unix_timestamp converted for comparison inside the select and the result also becoming modified for php's fetch_array

This seems to be the solution:

```
 SELECT *, Unix_Timestamp(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), '+00:00', '$user_timezone_offset')) as unix_timestamp
```

Actually this has a problem - although on

```
 mysql_fetch_array($result){ $row['unix_timestamp']; }
```

comes converted while checking on

```
  WHERE unix_timestamp=value //assuming unix_timestamp
```

to be converted on the select - in there it is not converted and another

```
  Unix_Timestamp(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), '+00:00', '$user_timezone_offset'))
```

has to be called for unix_timestamp to be "converted" each time a check is to be made against the converted value.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in mySQL, can you not do the calculation in whatever you're using to query the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating the issue.

Timestamps are always UTC.  When you retrieve a timestamp in PHP, it is in UTC.

When you convert a timezone using the `date()` function for example, it displays in whatever timezone the php.ini setting [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) is set to.

Therefore, if you have users with specific timezones, just call `date_default_timezone_set()` with the appropriate timezone prior to displaying dates in local time.

If you use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class, then you can specify the desired timezone when you construct the object.

Unless you have a very specific reason, there should be no need to perform timezone conversions when you fetch timestamps from the database.  PHP handles this all for you.

Comment: I have this problem also. I aggregate data by days, and resultset is associative array of key = dayte_timestamp and value = some_value, and when I want to hit array element directly from PHP, I have time zone problem because MySQL added timezone offset